# USART DMA misses the input string sequence

Tags: stm32

I configure my DMA in Normal mode. Here is my code:

```
void DMA1_Channel3_IRQHandler(void){ // USART3_RX 
        unsigned char CheckSum[2];
 
        Var1=Var1+1;
        if(Var1>1000){Var1=0;}  
    
        if(Buffer[0]==89 && Buffer[26]=='\n')
            {           
                
 
        Var2=Var2+1;
        if(Var2>1000){Var2=0;}  
 
                    
            }       
            DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TC3); 
            DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TE3);             
            DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel3, DISABLE);
            DMA_SetCurrDataCounter(DMA1_Channel3,sizeof(Buffer));
 
 
                
    }
void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler(void){
    
    if (EXTI_GetITStatus(EXTI_Line5) != RESET)
            {   
                if(GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIOA,GetPosition)==0 )
                    {                               
                            DMA_SetCurrDataCounter(DMA1_Channel3,sizeof(Buffer));
                            DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA1_IT_TC3); 
                            DMA_ITConfig(DMA1_Channel3,DMA_IT_TE, ENABLE);
                            USART_ITConfig(USART3, USART_IT_ERR, ENABLE);
                            USART_DMACmd(USART3, USART_DMAReq_Rx, ENABLE);
                            DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel3, ENABLE);
                            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA,SendSignalPosition);
                    }               
                else
                    {   
                            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA,SendSignalPosition);
                            DMA_Cmd(DMA1_Channel3, DISABLE);    
                    }           
                            EXTI_ClearITPendingBit(EXTI_Line5);
    }
}
```

Before each transmission, The transmitter change the PA.5 to low level , and if the receiver changes its SendSignalPosition pin(start DMA), the transmitter start transmitting and wait for 50us after all bytes being transferred.

This code works fine until I send some packages to the transmitter with DMA(TX) from the receiver. After sending some packages, the DMA looses the input sequence. I checked the variable Var1 and Var2 and I found out that Var1 is increasing ( the DMA is collecting the input bytes) but Var2 doesn't change after losing the input string sequence.

I need to know why this is happening while before each transsmison I disable/enable the DMA.

Comment: Why do you think the code is the problem? Have you ruled out other issues like glitches causing stray interrupts on your external interrupt pin? Get yourself a logic analyser and get a better picture of what is really happening.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've seen that the input pin(Receiver are you ready?) and output pin( I am ready to receive ) work fine and the transmitter start sending the bytes( I've checked the sending bytes with a USART->USB module). I think the DMA has something in its buffer which may cause this problem. Am I right?

Comment: You told us very little so far. I assume you have a debugger - interrogate the dma controller when it fails to see what it did etc.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I debug my code and I see that it the last character of the last input string is set to the first byte of my next receiving string at the receiver. It seems the last byte at the USART->RX register causes this problem.

Comment: Why are you handling this sequence yourself. Can't the USART module detect the transmission start on its own with the help of the Hardware Flow Control Features?